# INNODB mysql. Plugin disabled

Tags: mysql, innodb

When I startup mysql on my unbuntu server I will get a message.

```
121122 17:39:37 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121122 17:39:37 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121122 17:39:37 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
121122 17:39:37 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
121122 17:39:37 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
121122 17:39:37 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121122 17:39:37 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
121122 17:39:37 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
121122 17:39:37 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
121122 17:39:37 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
121122 17:39:37 [ERROR] Aborting

121122 17:39:37 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

a few times I have got a message saying that the plugin is disabled.

I use webmin to configure it. Could that be a problem?

Answer (score 4):

As CloudWeavers mentioned, you do not have enough memory available (including swap). If you do want to run in this configuration, either define an extra swap file like

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap.img bs=1M count=512
mkswap -f /swap.img
echo '/swap.img none swap sw 0 0' >> /etc/fstab
swapon -a
sudo chown root:root /swap.img
sudo chmod 0600 /swap.img
```

for a 512MB swap file (that is, an actual file) on your root partition (which is actually a hack to get you going - this is not a best-practice configuration) OR lower your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to a smaller value (again not recommended, this is an important tuning variable for the InnoDB engine and should not be changed light-heartedly)

```
sed -i 's/^.+innodb_buffer_pool_size.+/innodb_buffer_pool_size=32M/' /etc/my.cnf
service mysqld restart
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issues is :

```
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
```

And, if you are on GNU/Linux, we can take for granted that:

```
Errno 12: ENOMEM
```

It means that InnoDB initialization failed during memory mapping. You don't have enough memory available. I guess you don't have any swap defined (check with 'free -m') and you don't have  128MB free for InnoDB plugin?

This error automatically make the plugin go in 'disabled' and prevent you from using innodb tables.